# Header resize on scroll 100% screen height - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the code where i would like to add 100% instead of pixels. Can anyone please help me with this code? I'm bad at javascript

```js
function init() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
      shrinkOn = 100,
      header = document.querySelector("header");
    if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
      classie.add(header, "smaller");
    } else {
      if (classie.has(header, "smaller")) {
        classie.remove(header, "smaller");
      }
    }
  });
}
window.onload = init();
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="navcontainer">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage">POČETNA</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">BIOGRAFIJA</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#3rdPage">RURALNI MOTIVI</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="4thPage"><a href="#4thPage">REČNI MOTIVI</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="5thPage"><a href="#5thPage">GRADSKI MOTIVI</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="lastPage"><a href="#lastPage">KONTAKT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Short answer no, you cannot convert to percentage for scroll positions. Compute the number 100% in pixels instead.

Comment: Can you please provide your html too, or any snippet

Comment: Are you looking to set **shrinkOn = screen.height** ?

Comment: Yes, 100% of screen height

Comment: that is 100% screen height :-)

Comment: Add you `css` too buddy, how can I find out the solution without proper code.

Comment: never mind my bad, your answer is good, thanks

Comment: I just found the solution - **shrinkOn = window.innerHeight -1,**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `100%` but you can do it by using `window.innnerHeight`

```
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = window.innerHeight,
            header = document.querySelector("header");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header,"smaller");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller");
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
```

Comment: Good call, **window.innerHeight** is probably better than **screen.height** as I was suggesting.

Comment: Thanks, it seem simple. I tried with shrinkOn = screen.height  and shrinkOn = window.innerHeight and it almost works. The thing is i'm making one page website with full page scroll, so when i scroll to next page header doesn't change, only when i scroll one more time.

Comment: it looks like it's missing just one more pixel :)

Comment: Thanks for your help guys

Comment: Sorry, this code changes header **after**window height, do you know maybe how can it change **on** screen height

Comment: I can't help you without proper code. you need to provide it.

Comment: HTML: '<header>
 <div class="navcontainer">
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <ul id="menu">
   <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage">POČETNA</a></li>
   <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">BIOGRAFIJA</a></li>
   <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#3rdPage">RURALNI MOTIVI</a></li>
   <li data-menuanchor="4thPage"><a href="#4thPage">REČNI MOTIVI</a></li>
   <li data-menuanchor="5thPage"><a href="#5thPage">GRADSKI MOTIVI</a></li>
   <li data-menuanchor="lastPage"><a href="#lastPage">KONTAKT</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</header>'

Comment: `<header>
 <div class="navcontainer">
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <ul id="menu">
   <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage">POČETNA</a></li>
   <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">BIOGRAFIJA</a></li>
   <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#3rdPage">RURALNI MOTIVI</a></li>
   <li data-menuanchor="4thPage"><a href="#4thPage">REČNI MOTIVI</a></li>
   <li data-menuanchor="5thPage"><a href="#5thPage">GRADSKI MOTIVI</a></li>
   <li data-menuanchor="lastPage"><a href="#lastPage">KONTAKT</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</header>`

Comment: `<header>
 <div class="navcontainer">
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <ul id="menu">
   <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage">POČETNA</a></li>
   <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">BIOGRAFIJA</a></li>
   <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#3rdPage">RURALNI MOTIVI</a></li>
   <li data-menuanchor="4thPage"><a href="#4thPage">REČNI MOTIVI</a></li>
   <li data-menuanchor="5thPage"><a href="#5thPage">GRADSKI MOTIVI</a></li>
   <li data-menuanchor="lastPage"><a href="#lastPage">KONTAKT</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</header>`